# how to understand the relation between malloc size and process's VmSize and VmRSS?

Tags: linux, memory, malloc

I have a simple c program:

```c
void t_simple_case() {
    int *p = (int *)malloc(1024 * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
        p[i] = i + 1;
    }
    getchar();
    delete []p;
    getchar();
}
```

I only allocate 4096 bytes, but by `cat /proc/pid/status` I can see VmSize=5896 KB, VmRSS=2944 KB. Big differences.

So how can we understand the relation between my malloc size and virtual/physical memory usage ? How many parts can be added up to VmSize or VmRSS ?

Comment: That depends on the runtime implementation. At sizes in the kb range, the memory overhead for the runtime and the code itself is much larger than that. Try with several megabyte blocks  to see a difference